# JS-Dynamic Change of Overflow Causes Re-render in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, overflow

Here's the issue:

Dynamically changing a div's overflow property with JS causes the contents of that div to repaint/re-render - *only* in Firefox. In any other browser the div's overflow property resizes and the contents are NOT re-rendered.

Okay not a big deal, it may just cause the contents to flicker as they reload however, if you have a Flash item contained in this `div` (like I do), and then programmatically change the `div`'s overflow property this means the Flash movie will return to it's original starting state.

I've done very bare-bones testing on this, with a simple:

```
<div id="overflow_div" style="overflow:hidden;">
<flash object>
</div>
<a href="javascript:change_overflow();">Change Overflow</a>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function change_overflow() {
overflow_div = document.getElementyById('overflow_div');
overflow_div.style.overflow = (overflow_div.style.overflow=="hidden")? visible : "hidden";
}
</script>
```

Clicking the 'change overflow' causes the Flash object to return to its initial state in FF, but not in IE. This can be very frustrating when you're trying to create a dynamic experience with Flash and the Page interacting with one another...

So my question is simply:

Is there any known resolution to this?

OR

Is there any reason why this issue *still* exists in FF?

Comment: `visible` needs to be `"visible"` if it isn't already in your original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no way to prevent a reframe on overflow changes in Gecko.
2. Yes; fixing it requires a pretty serious rewrite of how plug-ins are hooked into the DOM and rendering tree in Gecko.  It's being worked on; see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90268.